# python - Detect language of a single charcter

Tags: python, python-2.7

I'm working on Keyboard Events Detector, using **pyHook** module. 
My next goal is in what language did the user type: Hebrew or English.

This is the relevant code for the topic:

```
def on_keyboard_event(event):
   ...
   print 'Ascii:', event.Ascii, chr(event.Ascii)
   print 'Key:', event.Key
   ...
```

I have no idea how to check the charcter, because I have no access to the text himself. Only to the ASCII Code.

Comment: You probably want to look up the unicode subrange for Hebrew, English, and also allow a "punctuation" type: as far as I know, both languages use the same punctuation characters.

Comment: If the event is only passing in an ascii value you can't tell if it is english or hebrew. There are only english letters and characters defined in ASCII. And some spanish/german/other latin based languages. You would have to use unicode (UTF-8) to be able to pull out hebrew letters.